# Graph Theory: Find a $K_{3,3}$ subdivision to this graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

This is my first post here, so I apologise in advance if some formatting is wrong.

In my graph theory class today we were challenged to find a $K_{3,3}$ (complete bipartite graph) homeomorphic to this [image].

I've tried to redraw, subdivide edges, and smooth some out, but I can't seem to find it. I'd appreciate any guidance or hints regarding which part to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{h,e,b\}$ be set 1, and $\{c,g,a\}$ be set 2.

- $b$ is directly connected to $c,g$ and $a$.
- $e$ is directly connected to $g$ and $a$, and is connected to $c$ via $d$.
- $h$ is directly connected to $c$ and $g$, and is connected to $a$ via $f$.

Comment: But you are using $a$ twice. $f$ has degree two, so it can't be in either of the two sets.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Oops, I see you corrected it too it seems.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try $\{\,a,c,g\,\}$ with $\{\,b,e,h\,\}$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!